# passenger wont find public path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, rbenv, ubuntu-16.10

I'm trying to setup my rails server and passenger wont recognize my app giving this error on log:

```
[error] 1473#1473: *1 "/home/myapp/public/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory)
```

or a 404 error in client.

i've done all troubleshooting possiilities to resolve but nothing.

here is my server block:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomaiin.com;
    rails_env development;

   # Turn on Passenger
   passenger_enabled on;
   passenger_ruby /home/myapp/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/ruby;

   # Tell Nginx and Passenger where your app's 'public' directory is
   root /home/myapp/public;
}
```

can anyone help me?

thanks

Comment: what is the path of your app?

Comment: run command `pwd` and check it

Comment: /home/myapp/myapp

Comment: check my posted answer and try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your root dir is in `/home/myapp/myapp`, update your server conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomaiin.com;
    rails_env development;

   # Turn on Passenger
   passenger_enabled on;
   passenger_ruby /home/myapp/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/ruby;

   # Tell Nginx and Passenger where your app's 'public' directory is
   root /home/myapp/myapp/public;
}
```

Comment: works perfectly, but wy? actually my app is in /home/myapp. so wy there is more one "/myapp"??

Comment: @Icaro your app is in /home/myapp/myapp directory, you can check the dir structure by command: `pwd`.